# How hibernate maintain cache for multiple java instances

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

Hibernate is an ORM framework which allows developers to handle database from application easily. It also allows multi level caching. Which is a great feature.

I know how does it maintain first level caching. 
https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/understanding-hibernate-first-level-cache-with-example

My concern is how it maintain first level caching while I have multiple instances of same application related/transact with same database?

Answer (score 3):

> My concern is how it maintain first level caching while I have
>   multiple instances of same application related/transact with same
>   database?

Each application runs in its JVM, so will have its own Hibernate `Session` (used for the first level cache) and its own Hibernate second level cache.

Note that in cases of running multiple instances of a same application, you generally wonder how to share the second level cache, not the first level that is specific  most of time to the current transaction.
And to get a distributed cache, you have to favor a distributed cache solution as [EHCache](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/integrations/hibernate.html) or [HazelCast](https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/caching/hibernate-second-level-cache/) that can set in front of Hibernate.